# CodeIgniter Active Record: Ignoring certain variables

Tags: sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'd like to use CodeIgniter's Active Record, and so far it's been working perfectly fine. However, I'd like to assign some variables to an object that I hope CodeIgniter can ignore when it generates its SQL query. For example:

```
$this->Objs->Name = 'Eric';
$this->Objs->Age = 27;
$this->Objs->Gender = 'M';
$this->Objs->TempVal = 'This is just for reference purposes';
```

I don't exactly have a corresponding column called `TempVal` in the table, so if I make a call to `$this->Objs->save();` (which implements a basic method that saves itself), the SQL query will include the `TempVal`, and this will trigger an error.

Is there any way to exclude `TempVal` from the SQL query?

Comment: See if this works for you `unset($this->Objs->TempVal); ` before save.

Comment: Hmmm, I trust this will work, but I'd like to use the variable after running the SQL query... do I really have to make some sort of dictionary to link them all up?

Comment: then store it in a variable, then unset() it and use it however you intend to use it! I don't really understand what you said about linking.

Comment: Actually I'd need to output this particular variable to the user, so it has to be in the object: I'd json_encode() the entire array of objects at the end of it. What I mean by linking is sort of like keeping track of the index so I can assign it after I'm done with the SQL...

Comment: mmm why not store in a temp var, unset(), save(),and then set it back to obj? Or maybe you save this infor in Session or Cookie...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subclass the `CI_DB_active_record` class located in system database. And modify the insert method to ignore your attributes you don't want saved.

[This](http://robotslacker.com/2011/05/extending-codeigniters-active-record-class/) shows you how to load it.  It requires a slight modifaction to load your subclass in `/system/DB.php`

Just for the record there is probably a much better way to do what you want to accomplish.